# WPF Set Window Title from Child

Tags: wpf, windows, user-controls, window

If I have a `UserControl` hosted in a `Window` that looks like:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do I set the `Window.Title` from the `UserControl`?

An additional requirement is that the `UserControl` can pull and set the window title from a static resx file such, i.e. `{x:Static p:Resources.MyViewTitle}`

**Edit**

After doing some more research, I think Attached Properties might be the answer. How might I go about implementing a `Window.Title` property that I can place on any child `UserControl`, allowing me to set the `Window` title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to create an attached property. See: [Creating a Window.Title Attached Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176655/creating-a-window-title-attached-property/)

Answer (score 2):

(Untested): Use [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx) to traverse the visual tree upwards until you reach an object of type `Window`. Then set the Title to `Resources.ResxFileName.MyViewTitle` (should be available in Code due to the auto-generated Resource classes).

Comment: Is there a XAML-only solution?

Comment: Good question. I guess you could use `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, Type={x:Type Window}}, Path=Title` to bind to the Title, and use `{x:Static p:Resources.MyViewTitle}` to bind to the value, but I'm not sure how you can *connect* these two bindings...

Comment: Yeah, that's about as far as I got too

Comment: Searching the parent tree is how I endedup doing it. I made it tidy by implementing it as an attached property.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event for the UserControl that the parent window subscribes to.

Comment: As the two are decoupled fairly well there is no place to hook up the events.